# Dashing dashboards. Retrieving data from google worksheet

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, google-docs, dashboard, dashing

This is the error I am getting and it's frustrating me

---

> syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
>   $.get^ ("https://spreadsheets.googl...

---

looking at the same code here ... [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfBN2/3/)

```
$.get "//spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1BN0MH3ZPpCq6Bh60a7Z09Np-fZUZzZOb3tXyCZRPvHs/od6/public/values?alt=json", (data) ->
r = 0
item_ = "["
i = 0
while i < data.feed.entry.length
   row = data.feed.entry[i].gs$cell.row
   cont = data.feed.entry[i].gs$cell.$t
   unless row is r
       item_ += " {:label=>" + cont
   else
       item_ += ", :value=>" + cont + "},"
   r = row
   i++
   item_ += "]"
   item_=item_.replace("},,", ",")
   item_=item_.replace("},]", "}]")
alert item_
return
```

its working

Comment: only some commented text... do I need to remove it

Comment: I tried removing the comments and still bringing the same result. The comments were done with a #

Comment: Do you have jquery loaded correctly in the page where you're running this?

Comment: require 'json'
require 'backports'
$.get "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1BN0MH3ZPpCq6Bh60a7Z09Np-fZUZzZOb3tXyCZRPvHs/od6/public/values?alt=json", (data) ->
  r = 0
  item_ = "["
  i = 0
  while i < data.feed.entry.length
    row = data.feed.entry[i].gs$cell.row
    cont = data.feed.entry[i].gs$cell.$t
    unless row is r
      item_ += " {:label=>" + cont
    else
      item_ += ", :value=>" + cont + "},"
    r = row
 i++
 item_ += "]"

Comment: Your question Joe got me thinking on jquery. I have gem installed jquery and did a require jquery on the script. The error is still there. When I did bundle show its not being included. I cannot install  jquery-rails since the versions required are conflicting. bashing requires ruby 1.9.2 while jquery requires 1.9.3. I dont know if this is the reason its not working

Comment: Part of the Gems installed are as below but still getting the errors.
<code>
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionpack (4.1.0)
  * actionview (4.1.0)
  * activesupport (4.1.0)
  * addressable (2.3.6)
  * backports (3.6.0)
  * buftok (0.2.0)
  * builder (3.2.2)
  * bundler (1.6.2)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
  * daemons (1.1.9)
  * dashing (1.3.2)
  * equalizer (0.0.9)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * jquery-rails (3.1.0)
  * json (1.8.1)
  * memoizable (0.4.2) </code>
Please help

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to add jquery because it is already included for you. Also, this uses Sinatra and not Rails, so jquery-rails won't do you much good. Also, don't fetch the data client side, fetch it server side. That way, the data will be in sync with all open clients. Check this example out: https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/issues/78#issuecomment-14940695. It uses something called 'roo' which apparently supports google spreadsheets.

Comment: my jobs/buzzwords.rb as below

require 'roo'
$.get "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1BN0MH3ZPpCq6Bh60a7Z09Np-fZUZzZOb3tXyCZRPvHs/od6/public/values?alt=json", (data) ->
  r = 0
  item_ = "["
  i = 0
  while i < data.feed.entry.length
    row = data.feed.entry[i].gs$cell.row
    cont = data.feed.entry[i].gs$cell.$t
    unless row is r
      item_ += " {:label=>" + cont
    else
      item_ += ", :value=>" + cont + "},"
    r = row
 i++
 item_ += "]"
 item_ = item_.replace("},,", ",")
return

SCHEDULER.every '1m', :first_in => 0 do |job|
  send_event('buzzwords', {items: item_ })
end